# Define a function for ng-click in an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I attach a function to be used with ng-click in an Angular directive?

I have defined my click handler in the `link` function. Using this function in my directive's `ng-click` attribute does not run it.

**Example:**

I have an angular directive called "card". When "card" is clicked, I want to change its `flipped` attribute from `false` to `true`.

**controller** - has an array of cards

```
$scope.cards = [
  {id: 23, flipped: false},
  {id: 315, flipped: false},
  {id: 182, flipped: false}
];
```

**directive** - renders a card, and has a function to "flip" it.

```
myApp.directive('card', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      card: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      // Create a function that will be called on click via ng-click.
      scope.flipCard = function(){
        console.log('fipped!');
        scope.card.flipped = true;
      }
    },
    template: "<div>I'm a card</div>"
  }
});
```

**html** - show all the cards

```
<div ng-repeat="card in cards">
  <card card="card" ng-click="flipCard()"></card>
</div>
```

When a card is clicked, the `flipCard()` function isn't being called. Why is this?

**Note**

I am aware of using `bind` to attach handlers in `link`. I am specifically asking why ng-click does not seem to have access to the directive's scope, as defined in `link`.  Here is a solution that works with bind. I am looking for a solution that works with ng-click.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  elem.bind('click', function(e){
    scope.flipCard();
  });

  scope.flipCard = function(){
    console.log('tap!');
    scope.card.flipped = true;
  }; 
}
```

Comment: you need to use transclusion if you want to take HTML elements outside the directive and give them access to the scope inside the directive.  Also, `scope.flipped` doesn't really make sense, because `flipped` is a property of the card, not a property of the directive....

Comment: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ng-click` on your `<card>` element tries to call `flipCard()` from controller's scope, not directive's one.

I'd write something like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Jvum0F?p=preview